# POST Request from Sharepoint 2013 XMLHtpRequest blocked by CORS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have a basic C# web API that I'm trying to call from a Sharepoint site. Currently, this is not deployed and is running in IIS Express right out of Visual Studio.   In my initial testing, I just whipped up a basic HTML page with a couple of textboxes, a submit button, and an AJAX call to show the API was working which it is.  But when I try to do this from Sharepoint I get the CORS error.

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:63123/api/MKT' from origin 'https://sharepointurl.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`

I tried:

1. adding the following headers to my web API's web.config file

   ```html
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,OPTIONS" />
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
   ```
2. Tried using a Chrome plug-in that disables COR policy.

However, the error persists. Any thoughts on what else I can troubleshoot to track this down?  I feel like this is either something on the IIS Express side or perhaps Sharepoint.

```js
<script src = "src=" //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" >

 function PreSaveAction() {

  var foldername = new Object();
  foldername.businessunitname = $("select[title='TestSelection1']").find("option:selected").text();
  foldername.dbatenantname = $("select[title='TestSelection2']").find("option:selected").text();

  $.ajax({
   url: 'http://localhost:63123/api/MKT',
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: 'json',
   contentType: "application/json",
   data: JSON.stringify(foldername),
   success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
    console.log(data);
   },
   error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log('Error in Operation');
   }
  });

 }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately what ended up working as a solution for me was to install the CORS module in IIS.  I also had to ensure I removed my other custom headers in the web.config file and then configure add entries for the IIS CORS module.  From there I'm good to go.  It is also possible I just needed to pass these headers in my POST request but I wasn't able to get that to work if indeed it was even a solution to begin with.